Microsoft VS не видит классы Unity
Подключил Unity к VS в Edit>Preferences>External tools, но при открытии скриптов в VS классы Unity не подсвечиваются. Так же VS не даёт рекомендаций. В VS в Debug есть Attach Unity Editor, но после выбора процесса, код просто запускается и ничего не меняется.
VS попробовал переустанавливать. Все расширения для работы с Unity в VS есть.


Нужно было просто скачать Visual Studio Editor в Package manager.
